# Syntax error on const {LEVEL,MESSAGES} when trying to run meteor application

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am taking over a project that has been developed using Meteor version 1.4.2.3. Upon running the project using `meteor run` I get the following exception:

```
W20180411-12:35:00.369(-4)? (STDERR) packages\modules.js:583
W20180411-12:35:00.603(-4)? (STDERR) const {LEVEL, MESSAGE} = require('triple-beam');
W20180411-12:35:00.603(-4)? (STDERR)       ^
W20180411-12:35:00.603(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20180411-12:35:00.604(-4)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
W20180411-12:35:00.604(-4)? (STDERR)     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
W20180411-12:35:00.604(-4)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\roberth\Programming Projects\xxx\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:289:30
W20180411-12:35:00.605(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20180411-12:35:00.605(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\roberth\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20180411-12:35:00.605(-4)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\roberth\Programming Projects\xxx\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:128:5
W20180411-12:35:00.605(-4)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\roberth\Programming Projects\xxx\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:344:5
W20180411-12:35:00.606(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (C:\Users\roberth\Programming Projects\xxx\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\profile.js:480:12)
W20180411-12:35:00.606(-4)? (STDERR)     at C:\Users\roberth\Programming Projects\xxx\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:343:11
=> Exited with code: 1
```

I've tried the following:

- Windows:

  - uninstalling nodejs v6 and installing v8
  - uninstalling meteor and reinstalling using choco
- Linux:

  - installing node using package manager (v6.12.3)
  - installing meteor using sh

The same error occurs on both Windows and Linux and I am honestly at a loss as to what is causing this issue.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

```
package.json

{
  "name": "meteor",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.18.0",
    "bson-ext": "^1.0.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "mongoose": "~4.4",
    "triple-beam": "^1.1.0",
    "winston": "2.x",
    "winston-mongodb": "latest"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As I was unaware that meteor uses a built in version of Node, I uninstalled node, meteor and deleted the repo. I then installed meteor via choco and cloned the repository. After running `meteor npm install` followed by `meteor run` I received the exact same issue with the unexpected token as described above.

**UPDATE 2**

I've been able to determine that the node_modules directory is at fault. If I copy the node_modules directory from a working machine to my dev box it works as expected.

**New question**: How can I determine which package is at fault? I'm hesitant to commit the node_modules directory into git as the fix and would like to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Just create a new project with the `triple-beam` npm package and copied your error-ing line but got no error. Did you run `meteor npm install` before `meteor run` ?

Comment: By the way you don't need to install node because Meteor ships with a version of node internally.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I did not know that it shipped with node - thanks for that tidbit. I had run npm install previously. I've also installed triple-beam which hasn't resolved it either. It appears to me that the issue is syntax related and almost like meteor isn't recognizing ES6 syntax

Comment: That seems to be a babel issue. Can you add your package.json excerpt of your dependencies?

Comment: @Jankapunk updated my question

Comment: Is the `ecmascript` package installed? (run `meteor list` or have a look at the `.meteor/packages` file in your project dir, assuming it was committed).

Comment: @MasterAM yep - its installed

Comment: can you run `npm list` against the working machine and bad ? Then do a compare of two.. Should show the installed version differences.. And I suspect that would narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Also, (un-related follow up) is it required to submit the `node_modules` folder ? Or can you let them install with fixed version in `package.json`

Comment: @Pogrindis the idea is that the package file(s) would allow you to build the project with the correct dependencies - this is whats falling apart for us. Thanks for the npm list idea - following up with that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your offending line comes from the winston-mongodb package. It has gone through 2 major releases since Meteor 1.4 was released.

Therefore most probably the semver spec `"latest"` in your `package.json` is way too loose. It allows a fresh install to pick up a recent version of the package, wich uses new ES syntax that is incompatible with the node version shipped with your Meteor version.

As suggested by @Pogrindis, you should be able to determine the correct winston-mogodb version to use by inspecting the `node_modules` of your working install.

You could also try upgrading Meteor. Version 1.6 now uses node 8+.

There is also the unlikely possibilty that the package in your working install had been transpiled locally. If constraining the package version still does not work, then this becomes more likely.

Comment: Thanks, I've started a new clean project and updated all the packages. Everything's building correctly now.